# Complex Esterification reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

**Question**
[image]

**Attempt**

On seeing the question it seems like simple esterification reaction and the answer seems A. But the answer in book says C. How is it so

I also tried to develop a mechanism as follows

[image]

Comment: Driven by the formation of the highly stable triphenylmethyl (trityl) cation. If you want the methyl ester add the cH2SO4 of a MeOH soln of the acid.

Comment: I am sorry but i didnt understand the last part. How do I get easter for above reaction?

Comment: To get the ester dissolve the acid in MeOH and add a catalytic amount of cH2SO4.